# Eclipse .jar creation image files not getting packaged

Tags: java, image, jar

I've created a project in Eclipse that has image files in a folder in the project space..

I've been creating .jars out of it all day, but now I have messed it up somehow.

I was testing what would happen if I removed the image files out the project and it obviously didn't work (as I expected). But when I copied the files back in and tried to repackage the project it is still acting as it did when I had no image files.. I can clearly see that the images are not being packaged into the jar because the .jar file is only 200kb compared to about 3mb with the images..

What have I done????

if it matters, the images are saved into src\main\icons and \src\main\Images.. also, I don't know how to use ant though I am planning to learn.. for now I'm packaging with Eclipse's Export -> JAR File

Comment: I'm not sure how eclipse export function works, but I would normally place images under `src\main\resources\images`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have copied the images in workspace directly( I mean not through eclipse) then you have to refresh the eclipse project and then export as jar because until you won't refresh the eclipse will not pick that file.

Comment: ok thanks that worked :) 

I should've tried that before asking haha, but maybe oneday someone else will find this question so perhaps it's not a complete waste of time,

thanks again